# How to cut a string with duplicates?

Tags: python, string

I have this string:

```
'fhsdkfhskdslshsdkhlghs
bksjvsfgsdnfsfbjfgzfga
avzaeafeaeaddacbytt!tw
fhsdkfhskdslshsdkhlghs
bksjvsfgsdnfsfbjfgzfga
avzaeafeaeaddacbytt!tw'
```

And I want to use this part of code for cut it in pieces of length 22:

```
from textwrap import wrap

w_str= (wrap(str,22))
```

And then I will got this:

```
fhsdkfhskdslshsdkhlghs

bksjvsfgsdnfsfbjfgzfga

avzaeafeaeaddacbytt!tw
```

The next step should take the last four letters and of the first string and past it at the beginning of the next and so on.
Just like this with an Id:

```
e_1
fhsdkfhskdslshsdkhlghs
bksjvsfgsdnfsfbjfgzfgaavza
e_2
avzaeafeaeaddacbytt!tw
fhsdkfhskdslshsdkhlghslghs
e_3
lghsbksjvsfgsdnfsfbjfgzfga
zfgaavzaeafeaeaddacbytt!tw
```

Comment: What language is this?

Comment: yeah. the language is python

Comment: not _valid_ python though...

Comment: @Anentropic how?I don't really understand

Comment: Which bit are you stuck on? make sure you're importing `textwrap` with no spaces or your code won't work

Comment: yeah of course! it was a mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you have your string as such:

```
_str = """fhsdkfhskdslshsdkhlghs
bksjvsfgsdnfsfbjfgzfga
avzaeafeaeaddacbytt!tw"""
```

You can do the following:

```
>>> _str = _str.split()
>>> new = [_str[i-1][len(_str[i-1])-4:len(_str[i-1])]+_str[i] if i > 0 else _str[i] for i in range(len(_str))]
>>> print '\n'.join(new)
fhsdkfhskdslshsdkhlghs
lghsbksjvsfgsdnfsfbjfgzfga
zfgaavzaeafeaeaddacbytt!tw
>>>
```

## Edit

`zip` two lists together in a list comprehension, as such:

```
'\n'.join(['\n'.join(item) for item in zip(['e_'+str(num) for num in range(1, len(new)+1)], new)])
```

---

```
>>> _str = _str.split()
>>> new = [_str[i-1][len(_str[i-1])-4:len(_str[i-1])]+_str[i] if i > 0 else _str[i] for i in range(len(_str))]
>>> print '\n'.join(['\n'.join(item) for item in zip(['e_'+str(num) for num in range(1, len(new)+1)], new)])
e_1
fhsdkfhskdslshsdkhlghs
e_2
lghsbksjvsfgsdnfsfbjfgzfga
e_3
zfgaavzaeafeaeaddacbytt!tw
>>>
```

Comment: e_1                                                                                                                                                                                                       fhsdkfhskdslshsdkhlghs
e_2                                                                                                                         lghsbksjvsfgsdnfsfbjfgzfga
e_3                                                                                                                        zfgaavzaeafeaeaddacbytt!tw

Comment: do you have an idea for give index to the output?

Comment: Give the index of what?

Comment: @yokie edited, if this answer helped you more, you should accept/+1 it instead :)

Comment: Hi, thanks. If I have more lines(more than 3) like 6 : the script cut the String in 6 pieces. I guess that the split() is the reason why i get this. I don't find how can I do for get only 3 substring (of length 44(it could also be 40) according to my question and if the string is duplicates)? I edited the question for show you

Answer (score 0):

In some ways, strings are like lists in Python in the way [you can reference their contents by index, and splice them and so on](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#sequence-types-str-unicode-list-tuple-bytearray-buffer-xrange).

So you could use the index of the characters in the string to pull out the last 4 characters of each wrapped string:

```
input_string  = 'fhsdkfhskdslshsdkhlghsbksjvsfgsdnfsfbjfgzfgaavzaeafeaeaddacbytt!tw'
split_strings = wrap(input_string, 22)

add_string = ''  # nothing there at first, but will be updated as we process each wrapped string
for output_string in split_strings:
    print add_string + output_string 
    add_string = output_string[-4:]  # "[-4:]" means: "from the fourth last char of the string, to the end"
```

outputs:

```
fhsdkfhskdslshsdkhlghs
lghsbksjvsfgsdnfsfbjfgzfga
zfgaavzaeafeaeaddacbytt!tw
```